# Get the maximum value from an array without the max() function in python

Tags: python, function, max

I want to pick the max valued number from and integer array. This is quite easy in python.

```
arr = [10,40,30,326,673]
print(max(arr))
```

But I actually want to know the behind the scene of this `max()` function. How does this pull the maximum value from an array?
How can I pull the maximum value from an array manually?
Here is my full code:

```
stdName = ["X"]
stdMark = [0]
Pass = ", Passed"
Fail = ", Failed"
stdNum = int(input("Enter number of students: "))
while len(stdMark) <= stdNum:
    name = input("Enter student name: ")
    mark = int(input("Enter student mark: ")
    if mark < 0 or mark > 100:
        print("Enter mark between 0 to 100")
    else:
        stdName.append(name)
        stdMark.append(mark)
for i in range(1,stdNum+1):
    if stdMark[i] < 60:
        stdName[i] = stdName[i] + Fail
        print(stdName[i])
    else:
        stdName[i] = stdName[i] + Pass
        print(stdName[i])
print(max(stdMark))
```

I want that `print(max(stdMark))` to be done manually without the `max()` function.

Comment: `max` also accepts an iterator function as an argument. You don't want to consider that? ;)

Comment: It might help if you explained why - do you want to implement the `max` function for fun?  For a class?  Because `max` doesn't do something that you want it to do?  For speed?

Comment: I actually don't want to use that 'max()' function. I want to do it manually.

Comment: You mention that you want to know "the behind the scene of this `max()` function" - do you just want to know how the builtin is implemented?

Comment: @Rakibul yes, you said that already: **why?** Have you tried to do it? It's not terribly complicated.

Comment: I want to learn how this `max()` function works. Just to gain knowledge.

Comment: I'm not getting the idea how to pull the max value from that array.

Comment: OK, to be purist `arr = [10,40,30,326,673]` isn't an *array*, it is a *list*. This may be misleading when you look at the title because arrays are something very much different as implemented in `numpy`.

Comment: Oh yes. This isn't an array. This is actually a list. My mistake.

Comment: @Rakibul it's not clear what you have a problem with - you haven't shown any attempt to write your own `max` function. Did you try? Where did you get to? What was the problem with it? Do you know how to iterate over an "array"? Store values from it? Compare the size of things?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I didn't know how to iterate over an "array". And I had no idea how to get the max value. So just asked for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct answer needs to use an iterator and work for any kind of item.

```
def maximum(items, default=None):
    iterator = iter(items)
    m = next(iterator)
    for item in iterator:
        if item > m:
            m = item
    return m
```

Comment: Yes. I got it. Thanks for the help. This does my job.

Comment: What's up with the `default` argument? You don't use it, and the built-in `max` doesn't take any such argument.

Comment: @user2357112 It's python3 only. Normal `max` errors on `max([])`, but sometimes you want that to be meaningful. `max([], default=0)` returns `0`, or perhaps you want `max([], default=-np.inf)`. But it complicates the code, so I left it out.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to implement max function:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x if x > y else y,[10,40,30,326,673])
673
```

You can see `python` builtin function source code, include `max` function [here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Python/bltinmodule.c).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to implement a max function is this what you're looking for?

```
def newMax(lst):
    max = lst[0]
    for k in range(1, len(lst)):
        if lst[k] > max:
            max = lst[k]
    return max
```

Comment: This will also modify the `lst` parameter. (No longer accurate)

Comment: Good point - modified.

Comment: Better, but you can do this iteratively and not assume your argument is a list.

Comment: This is fragile for `len(lst) == 0`. Consider starting with `max_ = None`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Normal max fails for empty lists as well, and it should. More recently a `default` argument was added for when you don't want it to fail in this case.

Comment: @U2EF1 fair point! But starting with `max_ = None` also allows dealing with unindexable containers like `set`.